# arc4random throwing out huge numbers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, arc4random

In a cocos2d game, I use arc4random to generate random numbers like this:

```
    float x = (arc4random()%10 - 5)*delta;
```

(delta is the time between updates in the scheduled update method)

```
    NSLog(@"x: %f", x);
```

I have been checking them like that.

Most of the numbers that I get are like this:

```
    2012-12-29 15:37:18.206 Jumpy[1924:907] x: 0.033444
```

or

```
    2012-12-29 15:37:18.247 Jumpy[1924:907] x: 0.033369
```

But for some reason I get numbers like this sometimes:

```
    2012-12-29 15:37:18.244 Jumpy[1924:907] x: 71658664.000000
```

Edit: Delta is almost always:

```
    2012-12-29 17:01:26.612 Jumpy[2059:907] delta: 0.016590
```

I thought it should return numbers in a range of -5 to 5 (multiplied by some small number). Why I am getting numbers like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`arc4random` returns a `u_int32_t`.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html)  The `u_` part tells you that it's unsigned.  So all of the operators inside the parentheses use unsigned arithmetic.

If you perform the subtraction `2 - 5` using unsigned 32-bit arithmetic, you get 2<sup>32</sup> + 2 - 5 = 2<sup>32</sup> - 3 = 4294967293 (a “huge number”).

Cast to a signed type before performing the subtraction.  Also, prefer `arc4random_uniform` if your deployment target is iOS 4.3 or later:

```
float x = ((int)arc4random_uniform(10) - 5) * delta;
```

If you want the range to include -5 and 5, you need to use 11 instead of 10, because the range [-5,5] (inclusive) contains 11 elements:

```
float x = ((int)arc4random_uniform(11) - 5) * delta;
```

Answer (score 1):

`arc4random` returns a `u_int32_t`, an unsigned type. The modulus is also performed using unsigned arithmetic, which yields a number between 0 and 9, as expected (by the way, don't ever do this; use `arc4random_uniform` instead). You then subtract 5, which is interpreted as an **unsigned** value, yielding a possibly huge positive value due to underflow.

The solution is to explicitly type the 5 by storing it in a variable of signed type or with a suffix (like `5L`).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `arc4random % 10` becomes less than `5`, and you are working with negative integer later.

What is the value of `delta`?